# How to remove the characters from multiple columns in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to remove the characters from the columns in the pandas' data frame. I got around 10 columns and each has characters. Please see the sample column. Column type is a string and would like to remove the characters and convert the column int float

```
10.2\I

10.1\Y

NAN

12.5\T

13.3\T

9.4\J

NAN

12.2\N

NAN

11.9\U

NAN

12.4\O

NAN

8.3\U

13.5\B

NAN

13.1\V

11.0\Q

11.0\X

8.200000000000001\U

NAN

13.1\T

8.1\O

9.4\N
```

I would like to remove the '\', all the Alphabets and make it into a float. I don't want to change the NAN.

I used `df[column name'] = df.str[:4]` - It removes some of the cells but not all cells. Also, unable to convert into a float as I am getting an error

```
df[column name'] = df.str[:4]

df['column name'].astype(float)

0     10.2

1     10.1

2      NaN

3     12.5

4     13.3

5     9.4\

6     8.3\

22    8.1\

27    9.4\
28     NaN
29    10.6
30    10.8
31     NaN
32    7.3\
33    9.8\
34     NaN
35    12.4
36    8.1\
```

Still it's not converting other cells

Getting error when I tried to convert into a float

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10.2\I'

Comment: Hi! It is frankly quite difficult to parse your post. Please format it a bit more clearly use some of the markdown/code-tags etc. available, and then I'm sure people will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons I can see why your code is not working:

- Using `[:4]` will not work for all values in your example since the number of digits before the decimal point (and apparently after it) varies.
- In the `df['column name'] = df.str[:4]` assignment there needs to be the same column identifier on the right side of the equal sign.

Here is a solution with a sample dataframe I prepared with two abbreviated columns like in your example.  It uses `[:-2]` to truncate each value from the right side and then replaces remaining N's with the original NAN's before converting to float.

```
import pandas as pd

col = pd.Series(["10.2\I","10.1\Y",'NAN','12.5\T'])
col2 = pd.Series(["11.0\Q","11.0\X",'NAN',r'8.200000000000001\U'])

df = pd.concat([col,col2],axis=1)
df.rename(columns={0:'col1',1:'col2'},inplace=True)
df

    col1     col2
0   10.2\I   11.0\Q
1   10.1\Y   11.0\X
2   NAN      NAN
3   12.5\T   8.200000000000001\U

#apply the conversion to all columns in the dataframe
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str[:-2].replace('N','NAN').astype(float)

df
    col1    col2
0   10.2    11.0
1   10.1    11.0
2   NaN     NaN
3   12.5    8.2
```